# My server simulation is getting locked up between receiving movement input from players and updating projectile position

Tags: networking, game-loop, server, node.js, websocket

I'm currently developing a 2D game in the browser with Nodejs and Canvas. Im simulating the world state in the server side with a timestep of 60 frames per second. Im only sending a snapshot of the simulation at 10 fps and interpolating client side.

This has worked really great as far as player movement is concerned. The problem I am facing is that I added projectiles, and when two players connect and shoot, the bullets get delayed by up to 3 seconds, then they are all rendered at the same time smoothly, but with that huge delay.

On each websocket message from the client, the request is added to a queue inside the simulation. The requests are processed inside the update loop, and then the bullets' positions are updated at each timestep.

I'm thinking since the client can send 8 bytes of movement 60 times per second, + 6 bytes of "shooting" a bullet 10 times per seconds, the simulation is being blocked and then renders the bullets late.

I'm not sure if running the simulation for the projectiles and player movement should be processed in different threads, or if there's a simpler solution to this.

Here's the code for the simulation and the server

Server Index.js

```
var express = require("express");
var http = require("http");
var path = require("path");
var WebSocket = require("ws");
var app = express();
var server = http.Server(app);

var { encodePlayers, decodeMovement } = require("./network/utils");
var { Simulation } = require("./simulation/Simulation");
app.set("port", 5000);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "dist")));
app.use("/static", express.static(__dirname + "/static")); // Routing

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send({ message: "Welcome to Xombie API" });
});
server.listen(5000, function() {
  console.log("Starting server on port 5000");
});

var exists = id => {
  if (id in players) return true;
  else return false;
};

const web = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

var simulation = new Simulation();

simulation.start();

web.on("connection", socket => {
  socket.onclose = () => {
    simulation.requests.queue({ type: 4, userID: socket.id });
  };

  socket.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
    if (data.byteLength == 0) {
      var id = generate();
      socket.id = id;
      simulation.requests.queue({ type: 0, userID: id });

      let buffer = new ArrayBuffer(2);
      let view = new Uint8Array(buffer);
      view[0] = 1;
      view[1] = socket.id;
      socket.send(buffer);
    } else {
      //different cases for messages
      let view = new Uint8Array(data);
      if (view[0] == 2) {
        simulation.requests.queue({
          type: 1,
          payload: data,
          userID: socket.id
        });
      } else if (view[0] == 3) {
        simulation.requests.queue({
          type: 2,
          payload: data,
          userID: socket.id
        });
      }
    }
  };
});

var encoded;

const update = () => {
  encoded = encodePlayers(simulation.players, simulation.projectiles);
  web.clients.forEach(client => {
    client.send(encoded);
  });
};

setInterval(() => {
  update();
}, 1000.0 / 10);
```

Simulation

```
"use strict";
let { Queue } = require("../ds/Queue");
var {
  encodePlayers,
  decodeMovement,
  decodeProjectile
} = require("../network/utils");
var self;
class Simulation {
  constructor() {
    this.requests = new Queue();
    this.players = {};
    this.projectiles = {};
    self = this;
  }

  update() {
    if (!this.requests.empty()) {
      let request = this.requests.peek();
      self.processRequest(request);
      this.requests.dequeue();
    }
    self.updateProjectiles();
    //self.checkHits();
  }

  processRequest(request) {
    switch (request.type) {
      case 0:
        self.addPlayer(request.userID);
        break;
      case 1:
        self.moveLogic(request.payload, request.userID);
        break;
      case 2:
        self.addProjectile(request.userID, request.payload);
        break;
      case 4:
        delete this.players[request.userID];
        break;
    }
  }

  addPlayer(ID) {
    this.players[ID] = {
      position: { x: 0, y: 0, radius: 30 },
      health: 100,
      sequenceID: 0
    };
  }

  projectileExists(ID) {
    return projectiles[ID] ? true : false;
  }

  addProjectile(ID, payload) {
    let id = self.generateID();

    let target = decodeProjectile(payload);

    let initPos = this.players[ID].position;

    let angle = self.setAngle(initPos, target);
    this.projectiles[id] = {
      angle: angle,
      userID: ID,
      position: { x: initPos.x + 30, y: initPos.y + 30, radius: 4 },
      ID: id
    };
  }

  checkHits() {
    for (let userID in this.players) {
      for (let id in this.projectiles) {
        if (this.projectiles[id].userID != userID)
          self.checkBulletHit(userID, id);
      }
    }
  }

  checkBulletHit(playerId, bulletId) {
    var player = this.players[playerId];
    var bullet = this.projectiles[bulletId];

    if (!player || !bullet || bullet.userId === playerId) return;

    let bulletPos = bullet.position;

    let playerPos = player.position;

    let dx = bulletPos.x - playerPos.x;
    let dy = bulletPos.y - playerPos.y;

    let distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

    if (distance <= bulletPos.radius + playerPos.radius) {
      player.health -= 10;
      if (player.health <= 0) delete this.players[playerId];

      delete this.projectiles[bulletId];
    }
  }

  setAngle(position, target) {
    let deltaX = target.x - position.x;
    let deltaY = target.y - position.y;

    let angle = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);

    let x = Math.cos(angle);
    let y = Math.sin(angle);

    return { x, y };
  }

  generateID() {
    //create 8 digit random id
    let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50000 + 1);

    if (this.projectiles[num]) self.generateID();
    else return num;
  }

  updateProjectiles() {
    var speed = 15;

    for (let id in this.projectiles) {
      let curr = this.projectiles[id];
      let { position, angle } = curr;

      var { x: aX, y: aY } = angle;
      let { x, y } = position;

      if (x < 0 || x > 1400 || y < 0 || y > 1000) {
        delete this.projectiles[id];
      } else {
        curr.position.x += Math.floor(aX * speed);
        curr.position.y += Math.floor(aY * speed);
      }
    }
  }

  moveLogic(payload, ID) {
    //decode
    let speed = 350;
    let { pressX, pressY, sequenceID } = decodeMovement(payload);

    let player = this.players[ID];

    player.position.x += pressX * speed;
    player.position.y += pressY * speed;

    player.sequenceID = sequenceID;
  }

  start() {
    setInterval(() => self.tick(), 1000 / 60);
  }

  tick() {
    self.update();
  }
}

module.exports.Simulation = Simulation;
```

Comment: What does your client code look like? I'd hazard a guess that its something to do with the fact you're only processing one request per frame. Are only rendering the bullets when the server tells the client?

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant to your problem, but `if (!this.requests.empty()) {` <- this will process at most one message per update and the rest will be kept until the next update. I would assume you want to process the *whole* message queue before updating the simulation. So I would use `while (!this.requests.empty()) { /* process the first message */ }`.